# What are the main categories of wood-turning tools?

Tags: tools, turning

For example, you have the spindle gouge:

[image: spindle gouge]

A parting tool:

[image: parting tool]

And several more. Walk into any wood-working store, and you'll probably see many of these sorts of tools, among others, that come in a great variety of lengths, dimensions, and shapes. Hence, I'm wondering if there's a broad categorization whereby tools in the same category are basically the same shape, just different sizes.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here - perhaps from lack of knowledge.  Are you asking what the name of the category is for tools like this (for example, if you were to look for an aisle label)?

Comment: @Joe: Indeed, I'm not particularly knowledgeable about this. My motivation is that I want to build a program that does some sort of analysis on a shape to be turned with these tools in mind, and a broad categorization of tools would help in reducing the need to specify each and every tool and its dimensions individually. I can have one spindle gouge model and scale it up and down as needed as opposed to having 30 different spindle gouge models. Does that clear it up?

Comment: I think for beginners this question could also ask roughly what each category of tool is for and when you would use it, eg gouges first for rough shaping, scrapers later for taking off the rough gouge marks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. There are gouges, which like you have displayed are made from curved pieces, bowl gouges, spindle gouges etc.
2. of course the parting tool is what it is, though there are different sizes.
3. skews - Angled on both front and back, can be straight, angled, or curved.
4. scrapers, often round nosed but many different shapes available
5. Then there are a whole host of texturing tools

   a.[Texturing and spiraling](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000OYJIOQ)

   b.Chatter tools
6. As BrownRedHawk pointed out there are Hollowing tools as well, to make empty vessels and vases.
   I'm sure there are plenty more too!

[image]

Comment: I would only add 'hollowing tools' as an additional category, as they don't easily fit into one discrete category, as the cutting face may be interchangeable, but use a gouge, scraping or (rarely) beveled cutting surface.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk yes I agree!  I wouldn't be surprised if something else comes up to, but I'll add those to the list.

Comment: Scrapper -> scraper

Comment: Cheers, I tried to edit, but you need more characters

Comment: @CaptainLepton yep, I think it's 10 or 15 chars worth of change.

Comment: I would have known that if I'd tried editing anything before!